# Custom session handlers and redirect

Tags: php, session

I have a small app, that redirects on successful user sign in and also on app initialization it defines custom session handlers. Redirect is done this way: `sprintf( '<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="%d;url=%s"/></head></html>', $delay, $url );` .

Now the question is. If I redirect this way, will it reach custom session handler during, that call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Use the `header()` function to send a `Location` header like so:

```
<?php header("Location: $url"); ?>
```

Add that before any output is sent. And yes, the session will remain.

Comment: So even with the way I do, it should reach `session_write` handler ( before it redirects ), right? And all objects defined earlier should remain till then?

Comment: The script will always run as a whole. If you don't `die()` after the redirect, anything past it will run and operate.

Comment: Thank you very much for help. Then problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: This statement at php.net is a bit confusing. `As of PHP 5.0.5 the write and close handlers are called after object destruction and therefore cannot use objects or throw exceptions. The object destructors can however use sessions.`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are redirecting that way.

```
session_start();

// do something

header("Location: some_url_to_redirect");
```